# Turning off the pager in git for the stash command only

Tags: git, pager, git-stash

I generally like the use of the pager in git, but for `git stash` the pager annoys me.  When calling `git stash list`, I don't want to be shown the three lines of output in the pager -- it forces me to press `q` just to make the output unavailable again when typing the folow-up `git stash pop` command.

One solution would be to use

```
git --no-pager stash list
```

but that's to much typing (I'm lazy).  Following the [man page of `git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), I tried

```
git config --global pager.stash false
```

but this doesn't seem to do what the documentation says (actually, I didn't notice any effect).  Then I tried

```
git config --global alias.stash "--no-pager stash"
```

again without any noticable effect.

The configuration gets properly updated, for example

```
git config pager.stash
false
```

It just does not have any effect.  What am I missing?  And how can I achieve that `git stash` does not use the pager?

Comment: Do you have any other pager-related config? Stash doesn't use the pager for me.

Comment: Strike that: the list subcommand does indeed paginate, and ignores the config.

Comment: See my answer below: `git config --global pager.stash false` not working was a bug fixed in git 1.7.7.3 and later.

Comment: @sven-marnach could you change the right answer to cbowns's one?

Comment: Another motivation for same goal: I religiously run `git stash show -v` before `git stash drop`, and I want the diff to remain in terminal (in case I did a mistake, or just for reference — frequently I do want to redo a small part of the changes in a different way).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

As of 1.7.7.3, `git config --global pager.stash false` accomplishes this.

Answer (score 11):

It looks like stash, and any other non-builtin command (written as a shell script, rather than in C) misses out on the pager config step. I sent a note to the git mailing list asking about this; it looks like it's a known issue, but not totally trivial to fix.

The primary reason you're seeing no effect from your alias is that git silently ignores aliases for built-in commands; the idea is that you never want to actually make a command inaccessible. For the alias to have a chance of being run, you need to name it something other than `stash`.

However, I believe that simple aliases are not permitted to affect the environment a git command is run in, which generally includes the options passed to `git` itself. If I use an alias like yours:

```
git config alias.foo --no-pager stash
git foo
fatal: alias 'foo' changes environment variables
```

If you want to do that properly, you'd have to use `!git --no-pager stash`, so that it'll spawn a subshell and reinvoke git.

Another temporary fix, since it's a shell script, would be to go edit `libexec/git-core/git-stash` directly. Just go find the `list_stash` function, and add the `--no-pager` option to its call to `git log`, or to cover the whole script, set `GIT_PAGER=cat` at the top.

Comment: Thanks for the info and for bringing this up on the git mailing list (I also read the answer to your mail there).  Regarding the alias:  I also tried a different name than `stash`, but the effect was the same.  Strangely, I did not get an error message (version 1.7.2.3), so I figured the name wasn't the reason.  I will just patch the script for now.

Comment: @Sven: Do you actually have more than one screen's worth of stashes to list? Or is your pager not quitting after less than one screen of output?

Comment: @Sven: And I'm not sure why you don't get that error. That check was added a long, long time ago (v1.5.3). The subshell alias (`!...`) should work fine though too, though, and avoid having to edit git itself.

Comment: As I wrote in my original post, I usually have just a few stashes, and certainly never more than one page :).  My pager (`less` of course) is not exiting anyway.  I figured out this is because I set the `LESS` environment variable in my `.bashrc`, so git does not overwrite it with `FRSX`.  I updated my `.gitconfig` to include `-FX` in the options to less manually, and now everything works fine.

Comment: @Sven: Aha! I was wondering if you had a nonstandard pager or something. Glad you found a way!

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively you can configure `less` to exit if there's less than one screen's worth of output:

```
export LESS='-F'
```

Or, verbosely:

```
export LESS='--quit-if-one-screen'
```

If you have colours in your git output, you'll probably also want to pass the `-r` flag:

```
export LESS='-F -r'
```

Comment: This solution is already buried in the comments to Jefromi's answer (somehow).  It is good to have it in an answer of its own, though.

Comment: Doesn't work here (xterm on pts) because after `less` quit, there is nothing left of less display, it redraws the previous prompts. But it works on the term "linux" on tty1.

Comment: Yeah, on some systems/terminals output disappears because it all goes to "alternate screen" and is immediately switched back :-(  Adding `--no-init` might help.

Comment: you can also do `git config --global core.pager 'less --quit-if-one-screen'` if you prefer to affect only git and not other `| less` uses.

Answer (score 0):

```
stll = "!git --no-pager stash list"
```

is your friend.