# How to apply `git --no-pager` for specific commands?

Tags: git, zsh

I realize that you can do `git --no-pager <command>` to prevent the output from being run through a pager.  I also realize you can use, for instance, `git config --global core.pager cat`.

However there are some commands where I do want to use the pager automatically, e.g. `diff`, and others where I do not, e.g. `stash`.  Typing out `--no-pager` each time is not as efficient as I'd like.

Is there any way to set configuration like this for individual commands?  As an alternative, is it possible to have `zsh` automatically insert `--no-pager` when calling `stash` without using an alias?

Comment: Related, but not duplicate since it concerns `stash` only, and not all commands in general: [Turning off the pager in git for the stash command only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225350/turning-off-the-pager-in-git-for-the-stash-command-only).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As [this answer points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225350/turning-off-the-pager-in-git-for-the-stash-command-only/8172857#8172857), you can use `pager.stash false` to turn off pagination for `stash`:

```
git config --global pager.stash false
```

More generally, you can use `pager.<command>` with other commands, like `diff`

```
git config --global pager.<command> false
git config --global pager.diff false
```

From the [official Linux Kernel Git documentation for `git config`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

> ```
> pager.<cmd>
> ```
>
> If the value is boolean, turns on or off pagination of the output of a particular git subcommand when writing to a tty. Otherwise, turns on pagination for the subcommand using the pager specified by the value of `pager.<cmd>`. If `--paginate` or `--no-pager` is specified on the command line, it takes precedence over this option. To disable pagination for all commands, set `core.pager` or `GIT_PAGER` to `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Git aliases:

```
git config --global alias.nop-stash "stash --no-pager"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  `stash --no-pager` generates an error, and `--no-pager stash` complains that the alias changes environment variables (which is actually what I *want* to do ... hmm

Comment: To see why this creates an error, see [Turning off the pager in git for the stash command only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225350/turning-off-the-pager-in-git-for-the-stash-command-only/4226181#4226181).