# What is the interactive terminal that some programs/ commands bring you into?

Tags: git, unix, zsh

I have created a new branch on git, and using `git branch`, I get put into this interactive window, with (END) at the end **(see picture)**. Is this a program like `less` or `more`? [image]

I would like to print out the contents of this program onto the actual command line, rather than this interactive app. I know that its not stdin, stdout or stderr.

PS: I am sure there is answer for this already, but I cannot seem to phrase the question to get answers.

Comment: That screenshot looks like it's the VSCode built-in terminal (based on the tab selections at the top) - did you run `git branch` from within the editor?

Comment: I ran it from the integrated terminal in vscode (on mac), so its still the z-shell. I have tried it in a normal terminal window and on a different operating system (Ubuntu), it does the same thing.

Comment: This seems to be a Visual Studio thing, not a command-line Git thing - but it may be the case that VS is running command-line Git, which sends its output to a pager. **If** that's the case, you can perhaps control the pager from within Git.

Comment: I have also used the normal mac terminal (without vscode), and also SSH'd into an Ubuntu machine. It has nothing to do with visual studio or vscode anymore. I got the same thing using the z-shell and bash. I have updated the photo too.

Comment: It has something to do with Z-shell or Oh-my-zsh. When I SSH'd into a machine without Z-shell, it worked fine. However, just switching from z-shell to bash on my mac, using `/bin/bash` **did not work.**

Comment: it looks like `less`. Try pressing the letter `h` on you keyboard and if you're directed to a `help` screen, then you know it is `less`. Something like `producer_program | less` ? But How or why that is happening I can't help with. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter `git` often automatically calls `less` when it needs a pager and `vim` when it needs an editor. Both can be configured, they're just the default.

Comment: @phd : Right you are! To flesh out the search a little further for the OP, I'll note that in a typical *nix environment, it would be the value of `$PAGER` so could replace `$PAGER` value with `cat` or `more` (traditionally ;-) ). Good luck to all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a **pager**, probably `less` by the looks of it. It switches away from the shell by sending a "terminal initialization" string to the terminal, then outputs there.

To have it print inline you can skip the pager:

```
git --no-pager branch
```

or use the `LESS` environment variable (on Linux at least - not sure about Mac):

```
LESS=FRX git branch
```

Where `F` = quit if the output fits on one screen, `R` = print colours, and `X` = don't send the terminal initialization string.

---

To make Git always skip the pager for `branch`, use this:

```
git config --global pager.branch false
```

[*Source*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8172857/4518341)

---

I asked a related question on Ask Ubuntu, and you might find more useful info there: [How does "less" switch to the text, then back to the prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/q/984209/301745)